# What is the best blending mode or opacity to use for printing?

Tags: print-design, transparency, blend-modes, packaging

What is the best blending mode to use for a pattern to give a transparent look in a packaging products? This product will be printed in CMYK colors, I attached samples of Black and cream colors.. For black example, I used rich black 60,40,40,100 / Cream 0,5, 25, 12
In the attached file, I used white on the top part and changed the mode to screen 25% But I am not sure if this is correct?
[The design look like the attached photo[image: ]]

Comment: any blend mode will work, since it will not be really transparent when you print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blending mode is just a visual screen effect. To have something not totally opaque, you will need to talk to your printer about what the substrate that is going to be printed on, they will also advise you on how colours may look if they are not opaque. Also remember if the transparent bits have a dark or light background, this will effect how the colours look.